# jQuery File Upload with custom Progress event and Ajax GC

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, garbage-collection

I've built into an app a File Upload with Progress bar using jQuery.ajax .

But I'm concerned that I don't understand how garbage collection will handle it and therefore how memory efficient it will be.
For the progress bar, I had to add a custom xhr in order to add a "progress" event.

**When will that custom xhr function and 'progress' event handler be cleaned up?**

```
 myApp.prototype.uploadFile = function () {

    $.ajax({
      type       : "POST",
      url        : posturl,
      xhr        : function () {  // custom xhr
                      var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                      this.onSaveProgress(myXhr, file);
                      return myXhr;
                    }.bind(this),
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      data       : postdata,
      beforeSend : this.onBeforeSend,
      success    : this.onSaveSuccess,
      error      : this.onSaveError
    });   

},

myApp.prototype.onSaveProgress = function (xhr, file) {

    if (!xhr.upload) 
      return;        

    xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function (e) {

      if (e.lengthComputable) {

        var percent = Math.floor((e.loaded / e.total)*100) + "%"; 

        $("#progress" + file.id).css("width", percent).text(percent);

      }

    }, false); // add new progress event handler

}
```

As you can see, I needed access to the **file** Object in the 'progress' event handler so I can update the correct progress bar.